# Remove/hide the item from the ng-option if the item is selected by another select box inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

How to remove/hide the item from ng-option inside ng-repeat if item is selected by another ng-option?

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
      <tr>
        <th>Column Name</th>
        <th>Map to field</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="head in headers">
        <td>{{ head }}</td>
        <td>
          <select ng-model="selectedColumn[head]" 
            ng-change="selectColumn(selectedColumn[head])" 
            ng-options="row for row in data">
            <option value="">select</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    $scope.headers = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]; 
    $scope.data =["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]; 
    $scope.selectedColumn = {};

    $scope.selectColumn = function(selectedhead) { 
      // $scope.fileData.headers.splice(selectedhead); 
      $scope.data = $scope.data.filter(function(item){ 
        return !selectedhead || !angular.equals(item, selectedhead); 
      }); 
    }
```

from above code the item get removed from data, however the  shows select.kindly advise, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></style>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="App"  ng-controller="selectController">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                            <th>Column Name</th>
                            <th>Map to field</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="head in headers">
                            <td>{{ head }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <select ng-model="selectedColumn[head]" 
                                    class="form-control"
                               ng-options="opt for opt in filterRow(head)">
                                <option value="">select</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>  
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('App', []);

    app.controller('selectController', function($scope) {
        $scope.headers = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]; 
        $scope.data =["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]; 
        $scope.selectedColumn = {};

        // use this insted
        $scope.filterRow = function(head) { 
            return $scope.data.filter(function(d) {
                return !(Object.values($scope.selectedColumn)).includes(d) || $scope.selectedColumn[head] === d;
            })
        }
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code does the job. I assume your question is, after removing all elements from `$scope.data` you don't want the user to access that dropdown which shows 'select', right?

All you need to do is disable the `<select>` tag when the `$scope.data` array gets empty.

The Code is illustrated bellow -

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 $scope.headers = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]; 
    $scope.data =["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]; 
    $scope.selectedColumn = {};
  $scope.emptyArr=false;
    $scope.selectColumn = function(selectedhead) { 
      // $scope.fileData.headers.splice(selectedhead); 
      $scope.data = $scope.data.filter(function(item){ 
        return !selectedhead || !angular.equals(item, selectedhead); 
      }); 
      console.log($scope.data);
      if($scope.data==""){    // this disables the <select> tag
       $scope.emptyArr=true;
      }
    }
   
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
      <tr>
        <th>Column Name</th>
        <th>Map to field</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="head in headers">
        <td>{{ head }}</td>
        <td>
          <select ng-model="selectedColumn[head]" 
            ng-change="selectColumn(selectedColumn[head])" 
            ng-options="row for row in data" ng-disabled="emptyArr">
            <option value="">select</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Hope That's what you asked for..
Cheers!

~ NiKhIL

Comment: if i am selecting an item from <select> tag then the item must be not available for any another <select> tag inside ng-repeat for e.g if i am selecting "alpha"  then "alpha" will be not available for next <select> tag inside ng-repeat. Hope that make some sense!!!

Comment: Yea, If you select 'alpha' from one <select> tag , its not visible in another <select> tag , its already in your code

Comment: Yes, however when an item is selected, the <select> tag set's to select

Comment: I got ya! then what you want it to be selected after you select an item? coz that item is gone from that array

Comment: my question is, what do you want to be selected when that item is deleted?

Comment: if the item is selected then that particular item must be not available for any other <select> tag. the above program does the same, However, when an item is selected the <select> tag doesn't shows the selected item

Comment: Kindly ref: https://christianfei.com/posts/Angular-Filter-already-selected-items-from-ng-options/